# using array.map with repeat in Javascript

Tags: javascript, repeat

Hello I have the following:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
```

I would like to update this array to:

```
a = [11,22,33]
```

I am trying to do something like

```
a.map(repeat(2));
```

but it results in an error.

I know I could easily loop through this, but I am trying to practice using more concise code, and expand my knowledge a bit on different functions, and how to use them.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: you need the objects as strings or numbers?

Comment: `let x = 2; a.map(e => e * ((1 << x) - 1).toString(2));` repeat as often as you want.

Comment: I need the objects as strings actually. I will try running toString on them to see fi that makes it work.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Why not just use `e => e * "1".repeat(x)`? :-D

Comment: @Bergi because i did not know `String.prototype.repeat`. Thanks :) tbh i generally don't know good ways to build strings in javascript that do not involve generating new strings over and over (like StringBuilder in other languages). That is a bit off topic though.

Comment: would you need `55` to turn into `5555`?

Comment: @Bergi this worked! thank you

Comment: @guest271314 thanks I was getting to that, but it was still too soon :) also Bergi commented not left an answer, so I wanted to thank him as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the number to string, repeat the value and convert it back to number.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3]
a = a.map(a => +a.toString().repeat(2));

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you seem to be looking for repeating the digits, use strings for that. Which have a handy [`repeat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) for this purpose:

```
a.map(x => Number(String(x).repeat(2))));
```

If you want to use your notation, you need to make a higher-order `repeat` function that returns another function to be used as the `map` callback:

```
function repeat(times) {
    return x => String(x).repeat(times);
}
a.map(repeat(2)).map(Number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible. You can define `repeat` as a function that returns a function:

```js
function repeat(times) {
    return function (value) {
        return +String(value).repeat(times);
    }
}

// Your code:
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var result = a.map(repeat(2));
console.log(result);
```

The `map` method expects a function as argument, so the call to `repeat(2)` should return a function. That (inner) function uses [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) after converting the value to string, and then converts the result back to number with the [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, `number` version and `string` version

```js
const doubleIt = n => Number(`${n}${n}`);

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 55];
const strArr = arr.map(o => `${o}${o}`);
const numArr = arr.map(o => o * 11);
const numFromStringsArr = arr.map(o => doubleIt(o));

console.log(strArr);
console.log(numArr);
console.log(numFromStringsArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of N `.length` with `Array()`, use `Array.prototype.fill()` to fill the created array with current element of `.map()` callback, chain `Array.prototype.join()` with `""` as parameter, use `+` operator to convert string to number

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3], n = 2;
a = a.map(el => +Array(n).fill(el).join(""));
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Note that `fill` is not supported in any version of IE.

Comment: @Andy Have not used ie in some time. There are several polyfills for `Array.prototype.fill` available as a gist or at github

Comment: Me neither, but I was working on an answer similar to yours and checked the MDN compatibility table for it. Thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @Andy It could also be mentioned that there are F(L)OSS browsers available for use, where a user is not compelled to use ie due to corporate or other externally imposed restrictions.

Comment: @Andy Find it interesting when a particular method or syntax is mentioned as not supported at the browser. That mention does not appear at `reactjs` or `jsx` questions as the users are expected to have `reactjs` or `jsx` defined. For any number of methods or syntax variations there could possibly be a browser which does not support the feature. You did not mention  arrow functions being used at the answers though they too could be unsupported at various browsers. Not sure why any individual would be using ie if not compelled to be necessity, or not be using the newest F(L)OSS browser

Answer (score -1):

Simply, try it with [Array join() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp):

```
a.map(x => Array(2).join(x));
```