# How to repeat the last few frames of animation for React Animation

Tags: react-native

I have an app which the user holds down the screen and an animation starts to play. This is not a normal animation. It uses multiple frames to create this animation much like a cartoon from Disney :)
The animation plays from the start to the end and loops. But I want it to loop over the last 4 or 5 frames repeatedly. At the moment it doesn't do this.

Here is the code:

Initialisation in the constructor:

```
this.animations = new Animated.Value(0);
  this.opacity = [];
  Images.map((item, index) => {

    this.opacity.push(
       this.animations.interpolate({
            inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
            outputRange: [0, 100, 0],
        }),   
      )
    })
```

The animation function and the hold screen function (for what it's worth):

```
startAnimation = () => {
  Animated.loop(
    Animated.timing(this.animations, {
      toValue: length - 1,
      duration: 50 * length,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    })
  ).start();

}

onItemMouseDown = () => {
  this.startAnimation()
this.setState({
  isOn: true,
  pauseToggle: 'down',
  mouseUp: 'no',
  twoSecOver: false,

})
```

The render:

```
{this.state.isOn === true ? (
        <View style={styles.container}>

          {Images.map((item, index) => {
            const opacity = this.opacity[index];

            return (
              <Animated.View
                key={item.id}
                style={[styles.anim, { animations: item, opacity}]}
              >
              <Image source={item.source} style={styles.animSize}/>
              <Text style={styles.timer}>Timer:{ms(this.state.time,{verbose: true})}</Text>
              </Animated.View>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      ) : null}
```

I've looked at this: [Looping over the last few entries of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611013/looping-over-the-last-few-entries-of-an-array)
and this:
[using array.map with repeat in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653792/using-array-map-with-repeat-in-javascript)
but I'm doomed to failure, so need some help.
I've been advised to call:

`Images.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map` instead of just `.map`? Set `startIndex` to `Images.length - 6` and `endIndex` to `Images.length` initially, then `Images.length-6` and `images.length` afterwards. This actually plays the last few frames on a loop but doesn't play the first 18 frames so isn't useful! I don't know how to get it to map through the first 28 frames, then start the loop through the last 6.
How would I incorporate that into the render?

I've also tried using Animated.Sequence (https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations#tracking-dynamic-values) but have no idea how to do it.

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

- Define a state for your images `stateImages` if you have already have the images you can define in the constructor:

```
this.state = {
  stateImages: Images,
}
```

- Remove the loop onstartAnimation and set a callback on the completion to start the loop

```
startAnimation = () => {
  Animated.timing(this.animations, {
    toValue: length - 1,
    duration: 50 * length,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }).start(({ finished }) => {
    // completion callback

    // if the user have the mouse down. You should track the current state because 
    // you want the animation if the user stop the action
    if (isMouseDown) {
      startLoopAnimation();
    }
  });
}

// The animation loop function
startLoopAnimation = () => {


  this.animations = new Animated.Value(0);
   this.opacity = [];
    Images.map((item, index) => {

    this.opacity.push(
     this.animations.interpolate({
     inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
                 outputRange: [0, 100, 0],
            }),
           )
         })
  let orderedImages = Images.slice(Images.length - 6, Images.length);
  this.setState({
      stateImages: orderedImages,
    });
  Animated.timing(this.animations, {
    toValue: length - 1,
    duration: 50 * length,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }).start(({ finished }) => {
    // completion callback

    // if the user have the mouse down. You should track the current state because 
    // you want the animation stop if the user stop the action
    if (isMouseDown) {
      startLoopAnimation();
    }
  });
}
```

Your render should be almost the same, but the Images map is processed with the stateImages that holds your current portion of the loop.

```
{this.state.isOn === true ? (
  <View style={styles.container}>

    {this.state.stateImages.map((item, index) => {
      const opacity = this.opacity[index];

      return (
        <Animated.View
          key={item.id}
          style={[styles.anim, { animations: item, opacity}]}
        >
        <Image source={item.source} style={styles.animSize}/>
        <Text style={styles.timer}>Timer:{ms(this.state.time,{verbose: true})}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      );
    })}
  </View>
) : null}
```

When the the user stop the animation action, you must restart your `stateImages`:

```
this.setState({
  stateImages: Images,
});
```

The code is untested but this is the idea.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work Ariel. It's making it sluggish and only plays the 32 frames with no looping of the last 6 frames. When you say completion callback do you mean actually put something there? Or just the if(isMousDown) like you have?

Comment: The use of completion callback it's because when the whole animation finish you want to loop the final 6, so i called the `startLoopAnimation ` to handle that.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to remove the direction toggle plz?

Comment: Sure. I already edited. I thought you want a loop with a reversal

Comment: I was getting an error saying can't find startLoopAnimation variable, I added this.startLoopAnimation and it removed the error, but the animation still doesn't loop over the last few frames. :(

Comment: Me again - I bet you are getting loads of notifications sorry! I've console logged the loop animations function and this appears to be working, but it's not looping in the render, only playing once.

Comment: Two things. 1) please log the render function to be sure the `setState` function is requesting the re-rendering of the component on each loop. 2) Be sure to use the array of images inside your state, not the `Images` array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215230/discussion-between-tom-and-ariel-perez).

Comment: Although there a major problems with the output, Ariel did answer the initial question.